# loop each item inside promise and filter the result

Tags: javascript

Hello i have this array

```
ids= [
       [234, 235, 236],
       [237, 238, 239, 240],
       [241, 242, 243, 244, 245]]
```

I want to loop each id on each array **inside the promise** to get a price each id and return a min price in the result of promise a each array example of expected result

```
priceMin= [
            [price: 100] // min price id 235, 
            [price: 120], // min price id 238
            [price: 180] // min price id 244
           ]
```

I do this but is don't work

```
async getSkusAndProducts() {
      const id = this.ids;
      const app = { $axios: this.$axios };
      const promisesPrices = id.map((price) =>
        endPoint.getPrice(app, price)
      );
      const data = await Promise.all([
        promisesPrices.reduce((prev, curr) => (prev.id < curr.id ? prev : curr))
      ]);
      return data;
    }
```

Please help me thank you

Comment: Don't do the `reduce` on the array of promises. Do it on the `data`.

Comment: thanks @bergi but i wan't to iterate arrays o array inside promise and find the array result if item have price min

Comment: Whatever you want to do with the result value of a promise, you have to do it inside a `.then()` callback or after an `await`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are obtaining prices from your server using the `axios`.  To simulate that part, let me first implement the mock function for your `endPoint.getPrice()` as follows.

```
/* dummy function to mock your axios call */
function getPrice (ids) {
  const prices = {
    "234": 300,
    "235": 100,
    "236": 400,
    "237": 140,
    "238": 120,
    "239": 150,
    "240": 310,
    "241": 210,
    "242": 500,
    "243": 400,
    "244": 180,
    "245": 192,
  };
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(ids.map(id => prices[id]));
  });
}
```

This will take your `ids` array and returns the price list in `Promise`.  Your axios app also returns `Promise`.  So it is similar.  You can see how it works as follows:

```
getPrice(ids[0]).then(console.log);
getPrice(ids[1]).then(console.log);
getPrice(ids[2]).then(console.log);
```

Now, your code;

```
const promisesPrices = id.map((price) =>
        endPoint.getPrice(app, price)
);
```

returns the array of `Promises` and the program keeps executing the next line without waiting for fetching data from the server.  So you won't be able to actually handle the price data in the following lines.

The easiest way in this case is to pass the callback to the asynchronous function as:

```
getPrice(id).then(prices => ({ price: Math.min(...prices) }))
```

When the asynchronous task is done (i.e. resolved) the price list is passed to the callback.  And the array of prices are now passed to `Math.min()` with the spread operator.

Here is the rewrite of your `getSkusAndProduct()`.  I also make use of `Math.min()` to obtain the lowest price.

```
async function getSkusAndProducts (ids) {
  const minPrices = await Promise.all(ids.map(id =>
    getPrice(id).then(prices => ({ price: Math.min(...prices) }))
  ));
  return minPrices;
}
```

Actually, the above code is redundant.  Writing the keyword `await` does not actually wait.  It still returns the array of `Promise` and set it to `minPrices`.  It is just an another way to write the callback style writing such as `.then(callback)` in two lines.  In this case we don't want to assign the result to `minPrices` in the callback so we can simply return the array of `Promise` directly as follows.  Note that you don't need `async` modifier since you are not using `await`.  It is simple and beautiful!

```
function getSkusAndProducts (ids) {
  return Promise.all(ids.map(id =>
    getPrice(id).then(prices => ({ price: Math.min(...prices) }))
  ));
}
```

You can run and see with the complete code below.  I use the redundant version of `getSkusAndProducts()` below since it may look easier to read with `minPrices` variables.  Replace with the shorter version and confirm that both works the same.

```js
const ids = [
  [234, 235, 236],
  [237, 238, 239, 240],
  [241, 242, 243, 244, 245]
];

/*
 * dummy function to mock your axios call
 * that returns Promise
 */
function getPrice (ids) {
  const prices = {
    "234": 300,
    "235": 100,
    "236": 400,
    "237": 140,
    "238": 120,
    "239": 150,
    "240": 310,
    "241": 210,
    "242": 500,
    "243": 400,
    "244": 180,
    "245": 192,
  };
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(ids.map(id => prices[id]));
  });
}

async function getSkusAndProducts (ids) {
  const minPrices = await Promise.all(ids.map(id =>
    getPrice(id).then(prices => ({ price: Math.min(...prices) }))
  ));
  return minPrices;
}

(async function main () {
  const minData = await getSkusAndProducts(ids);
  console.log(minData);
})();

/* or equivalently you can simply run as */
// getSkusAndProducts(ids).then(console.log);
```

**Appendix**

To answer your additional comment, you can run the following version 2 code.

```
function getSkusAndProductsV2 (ids) {
  return Promise.all([
    ...(ids.map(id => getPrice(id))),
    ...(ids.map(id => getPrice(id).then(prices => ({ price: Math.min(...prices) }))))
  ])
}
```

The first `getPrice()` will simply returns the array of prices when resolved.  The second one with the `then(callback)` will return the minimum price list as follows:

```
[
  [ 300, 100, 400 ],
  [ 140, 120, 150, 310 ],
  [ 210, 500, 400, 180, 192 ],
  { price: 100 },
  { price: 120 },
  { price: 180 }
]
```

Comment: thanks @waterloos but i have a question if my promise.all have two promise inside like this `const data = await Promise.all([promisesProducts, promisesPrices]);` and i want to add a `Math min` or `reduce()` for the result of promisesPrices not to promisesProducts how to do ? finally have one array for products and min prices

Comment: There are no harms putting more arrays of promises in `Promise.all()`.  Just make sure to flatten the array of arrays as `Promise.all([promissesProducts, promisesPrices.then(price => {do your work here})].flat()])`.  If you don't add callback to `promissesProducts`, the result of asynchronous task will simply be returned at the end.   You can experiment that with the code in my answer by adding another `getPrice()` call inside the `Promise.all()` without setting the callback.  The first `getPrice()` will return your price data, and the second one with the callback returns min prices.

Comment: I added appendix in the answer regarding to your comment.  I used the spread operator instead of `Array.flat()` though.

Answer (score 0):

This is a "variation on the theme", as I don't have access to your AJAX source. I am running the snippet against the publicly available typicode.com resource and I am getting the `name` attribute (instead of the price) from each returned request. The requests are grouped on two levels and put into `Promise.all()` calls. At the end the array `D` contains all the collected data (`id`s and `name`s) for each group and I use a simple reduce to find the "smallest" element per group.

```js
const ids=[[234, 235, 236],
           [237, 238, 239, 240],
           [241, 242, 243, 244, 245]],
      res=[];
      url="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/";

Promise.all(ids.map(idgrp=>
 Promise.all(idgrp.map(id=>fetch(url+id).then(r=>r.json()).then(d=>[d.id,d.name])))))
  .then(D=>{ // at this point all data is collected in D
   console.log(D); // all names
   console.log(D.map(d=>d.reduce((a,c)=>
    c[1]<a[1]?c:a))); // "smallest" name per group
})
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important}
```

Alternative version, using your own data (prices) and a dummy promise:

```js
const ids=[[234, 235, 236],
           [237, 238, 239, 240],
           [241, 242, 243, 244, 245]],
      fetchPrice=id=>new Promise(rslv=>rslv({"234":300,"235":100,"236":400,"237":140,
                                             "238":120,"239":150,"240":310,"241":210,
                                             "242":500,"243":400,"244":180,"245":192 }[id])),
      res=[];

Promise.all(ids.map(idgrp=>
// in the real code:       fetch(url+id).then(r=>r.json()).then(d=>[id,d])))))
 Promise.all(idgrp.map(id=>fetchPrice(id)                 .then(d=>[id,d])))))
  .then(D=>{ // at this point all data is collected in D
   console.log(D); // all IDs and prices
   console.log(D=D.map(d=>d.reduce((a,c)=>
    c[1]<a[1]?c:a))); // "smallest" price per group
   console.log(D.map(d=>({price:d[1]}))) // if you want the prices only ...
})
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important}
```